# A question that is answering itself

Tags: support, asking-questions, close-reasons

I am not talking about self answered questions.

Suppose the body of a question has answered itself. In that case, what action shall we take? Shall we close the question? If yes under what reason?

Comment: Yes, such question should either be closed or be split in QA format. It would be useful if you can link an example

Comment: I would not like to give any specific examples @Paṇḍyā

Comment: I think my question is answerable without seeing an example. I just wanted to know if we can close such questions or not @Paṇḍyā

Comment: The appropriate response is not to close the question. It’s to move the answer part of the question into an answer.

Comment: `Suppose the body of a question has answered itself` - Are they aware that they answered their question? if not, then better to explain them. Mostly they will rephrase the question. If they already know that they themselves answered their question then it is better to separate the Q&A as Keshav suggested.